# PATH_THIRD not working

Tags: ee2-upgrades, path

I upgraded the ExpressionEngine from v2.6.1 to 2.7.3. After upgrade, I am seeing error message for third party addons which couldn't include the file having like

```
require_once reduce_double_slashes(PATH_THIRD.'ep_better_workflow/config.php');
```

I found that PATH_THIRD isn't correct and having the value as '/' due to which all the path included with PATH_THIRD are showing error message.

Could anyone please suggest me.

Thanks,